# How to extract months between two dates in YYYYMMDD format in as400

Tags: db2

I have as400 db where we have two dates both are in YYYYMMDD format.

I am trying to exctract months between these dates

Below is my Query

```
SELECT MONTH(TO_DATE) - MONTH(FROM_DATE) as Months
FROM GREY  WHERE ID='1234'
```

This returns Months as 0

Where as YEAR(TO_DATE) - YEAR(FROM_DATE) is working.

My inputs are TO_DATE - 20160712   ;  FROM_DATE  - 20140728 . Expecting 24 months as answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-months-between) and [CEIL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-ceiling-ceil)

```
with grey (id,TO_DATE,FROM_DATE) as (values ('1234','2016-07-12','2014-07-28'))
SELECT
  CEIL(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE,FROM_DATE)) as Months
FROM GREY
WHERE ID='1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-timestampdiff)

```
with grey (id,TO_DATE,FROM_DATE) as (values ('1234',date('2016-07-12'),date('2014-07-28')))
SELECT
  timestampdiff(64, cast(timestamp(TO_DATE) - timestamp(FROM_DATE) as char(22))) as Months
FROM GREY
WHERE ID='1234';
```

Note however, that the `timestampdiff()` rules mean that the above returns 23 and not 24 as you wanted.  Since the start date is the 28th of the month and the end date is the 12th.

You could get the results you wish by adding [LAST_DAY()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-last-day)

```
with grey (id,TO_DATE,FROM_DATE) as (values ('1234',date('2016-07-12'),date('2014-07-28')))
SELECT
  timestampdiff(64, cast(timestamp(last_day(TO_DATE)) - timestamp(last_day(FROM_DATE)) as char(22))) as Months
FROM GREY
WHERE ID='1234';
```